# Create a playlist using SDK - SoundCloud - iOS

Tags: ios, soundcloud, playlist

Platform: iOS

I am making an app that will let users vote on tracks shared by others. These tracks will get added to some kind of grouped list. Currently, I require new playlists to be generated to a user's account. Is this possible with Soundcloud SDK?

Could soundcloud groups also be generated through the sdk? I am trying to keep as much of this on soundcloud's platform without delving into making a complicated backend myself.

Summarily, is it possible to create Soundcloud playlists or groups using the soundcloud SDK?

Comment: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#creating-sets

Comment: @santhu ah I probably was having a trouble finding a solution as they are called sets. Thank you for the link, however that documentation doesn't contain example code for Cocoa.